# DropDown List DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable, html-select

I've got the problem in my project. I use the DataTable plugin in my project.     I have table, where data are load from database. Each row have a drop down list.

If I load the page my table have a 10 rows, and this select work correctly, but if I click paginate button, and load other data my dropdown list doesnt work. 
If I page, sort, or use prev next buttons the event is ignored. Actually it does not work at all. I do not know what might be the cause.

Please, someone help.

cnt3 - select

```
$('.cnt3').on('change', '', function (e) {
var valueSelected = this.value;
alert(valueSelected);
});
```

Comment: It's because the dropdownlist loses its binding when you redraw the table. You will need to rebind the controls in the datatable callback function - fnDrawCallback is the v.1.9 version

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f0j8nuLw/

Comment: i checked fnDrawCallback but it doesnt work ;/